# CONDITION WHICH VERIFY THE 2 FIRST CARACTER

Tags: r

I am working in R, this is a look of my table :

```
IAE_2017    IAE_2018

L1PYSH      L2PYSH

M1CHIMIE    M2CHIMIE
.....      ........
```

Now I want to make a condition which take the 2 first caracters of IAE_2017 and verify if it is different for the 2 fisrt's of IAE_2018.

Comment: Share your data using `dput`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `substr()`, assuming `df` a dataframe :

```
substr(df[,1], start = 1, stop = 2)==substr(df[,2], start = 1, stop = 2)
```